# Visible rows in recyclerview jump ahead a little after rotate from portrait to landscape

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-recyclerview, screen-rotation

I have a problem which I will be grateful if someone helps me through.
I have a RecyclerView which fetches data from Server by issuing Request. when the rotate changes I resend that response by using onSaveInstanceState so that it doesn't send Request again unless it requires loadMore.
But when it changes from portrait to landscape, the first few rows jump ahead in measure of one Tab like the picture below ->

[image]

[image]

It fixes using scroll afterward.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_list);

    findViews();
    extractDataFromBundle();

    init();
    setListeners();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        vodOrAod = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("vodOrAod");

        if (vodOrAod == true) {
            vodFilmAbsListOutputStore = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ResponseVODFilmList");
            films.addAll(vodFilmAbsListOutputStore.results);
            showCaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {
            aodTrackAbsListOutputStore = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ResponseAodTracks");
            aodTrackAbses.addAll(aodTrackAbsListOutputStore.results);
            showCaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        startIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("startIndex");
    } else {
        loadMore();
    }


}

 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (tagDet.type.equals(EnumObjectType.VOD_FILM)) {
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable("ResponseVODFilmList", vodFilmAbsListOutputStore);
        vodOrAod = true;
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("vodOrAod", vodOrAod);
    } else {
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable("ResponseAodTracks", aodTrackAbsListOutputStore);
        vodOrAod = false;
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("vodOrAod", vodOrAod);
    }

    savedInstanceState.putInt("startIndex", startIndex);

}

 private void loadMore() {
    if (tagDet.type.equals(EnumObjectType.VOD_FILM)) {
        progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        apiRequest.getVODFilmList(
                new GetListInput(
                        tagDet,
                        startIndex + "",
                        startIndex + Constants.LIMIT + ""
                )
        );

    } else {
        progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        apiRequest.getAodTracks(
                new GetListInput(
                        tagDet,
                        startIndex + "",
                        startIndex + Constants.LIMIT + ""
                )
        );
    }

    startIndex += Constants.LIMIT;
}



private void onFilmListByTagResponse(VODFilmAbsListOutput vodFilmAbsListOutput) {
    if (vodFilmAbsListOutputStore == null) {
        vodFilmAbsListOutputStore = vodFilmAbsListOutput;
    } else {
        vodFilmAbsListOutputStore.results.addAll(vodFilmAbsListOutput.results);
    }
    switch (vodFilmAbsListOutput.status) {
        case DONE:
            progressView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            films.addAll(vodFilmAbsListOutput.results);
            showCaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: see http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/